# Unable to create a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, textarea, getelementbyid

I am creating an app that will tell you the price of a product when the barcode is scanned. Basically, when a barcode is scanned, it goes into the text field, and then based on which barcode it is, the textarea will have a price put into it via javascript. I've gotten this to work, but I can't seem to create a certain variable to save me from looking through tons of code later on.

Here is my javascript:

```
function showPrice() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('barcode').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML;
    if (userInput === "783466209834") {
        price = "16.99";
    } else {
        price = "Not a valid barcode";
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="text" class="textinput" id="barcode">
<input type="button" onclick="showPrice()" value="Submit">
<textarea name="" cols="" rows="" readonly="readonly" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Right now, my code isn't working, but if I remove

```
var price = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML;
```

and replace "price" in the if statement respectively, then it works. I'm not sure why I can't create this price variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're storing the *value* of the `innerHTML` as the variable, not storing a *reference* to it.

Change it to `var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');` and then `textarea.innerHTML = "16.99"` and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed it was something little I was missing, but it seems kind of strange that I can have a .value in a variable but not .innerHTML

Comment: No, you can have an `innerHTML` in a variable. It'll just be the contents of the `innerHTML` and not a reference to the property map.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes more sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the innerHTML of the `textarea` and storing it in the variable `price`.  Instead, you need to only store the element in the variable and then call `price.innerHTML` to place your result in the DOM.  Like such:

```
function showPrice() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('barcode').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('textarea');
    if (userInput === "783466209834") {
        price.innerHTML = "16.99";
    } else {
        price.innerHTML = "Not a valid barcode";
    }
}
```

EDIT: As talemyn correctly points out, you should use `.value` rather than `.innerHTML` for altering the contents of `textarea`s.  While it might look like it does the same thing, there are slight disadvantages that come with the use of `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with the value of the textarea, you need to access `document.getElementById('textarea').value`, not `innerHTML`.

And, yes, as others have pointed out, you want to set the variable to reference to the element, not the value.  Then you can retrieve or set the value of the element.

Answer (score -1):

You should not assign a value to `price` and then overwrite it... That's what your code is doing. I believe you think you are creating a storage location in the innerHTML?

Instead, just create the variable:

```
var price;
```

Run your code as you did; and then put the result into the page with

```
document.getElementById("text area").innerHTML = price;
```

Answer (score -2):

You're setting the 'price' variable twice with two separate things. You're not actually changing the DOM. Instead use:

```
var price = document.getElementById('textarea');
if (userInput === "783466209834") {
    price.innerHTML = "16.99";
} else {
    price.innerHTML = "Not a valid barcode";
}
```